# Best way to handle ajax upload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload

`form_for @model, :remote => true, :html => {:multipart => true }` does not allow us to send file via ajax.

I have found this but it's not up to date and it relies on dependancies :

- http://khamsouk.souvanlasy.com/articles/ajax-file-uploads-in-rails-using-attachment_fu-and-responds_to_parent
- http://www.williambharding.com/blog/rails/rails-ajax-image-uploading-made-simple-with-jquery/

Anyone with up to date ressources ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is example for uploading File on Rails 3 using Jquery.

Make use of it, it is simple

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/jQuery-File-Upload-for-Rails-3

Answer (score 0):

I've used Uploadify in a recent application http://www.uploadify.com/  Some Rails specific notes here http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/07/21/uploadify-and-rails23/  I know you said Rails 3, but the concepts are the same.